# My app screen doesn't fit the AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am trying to load my app in the AVD. But, the screen of my app does not fit in the AVD. The AVD cuts the screen and doesn't provide any scroll to go down. The Email EditText & everything below it is not displayed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/homescreen_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/EmployeeInfo_heading"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="75dp"
         android:layout_gravity="right"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         android:contentDescription="@string/EmployeeInfo_profile_pic"
         android:src="@drawable/profile"/>

     <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView 
                android:text="@string/EmployeeInfo_emp_id"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emp_id"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView 
                android:text="@string/EmployeeInfo_emp_name"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emp_name"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView 
                android:text="@string/EmployeeInfo_emp_mobile_no"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emp_mobile_no"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:inputType="number" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView 
                android:text="@string/EmployeeInfo_emp_pan_no"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emp_pan_no"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:inputType="text"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView 
                android:text="@string/EmployeeInfo_emp_passport_no"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emp_passport_no"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:inputType="text"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView 
                android:text="@string/EmployeeInfo_emp_email"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emp_email"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView 
                android:text="@string/EmployeeInfo_emp_addr"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emp_addr"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"/>

        </TableRow>
     </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The stings.xml is included below

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">EmployeeApp</string>
    <string name="EmployeeInfo_heading">Profile</string>
    <string name="EmployeeInfo_profile_pic">Profile picture</string>
    <string name="EmployeeInfo_emp_id">Employee Id</string>
    <string name="EmployeeInfo_emp_name">Name</string>
    <string name="EmployeeInfo_emp_mobile_no">Mobile</string>
    <string name="EmployeeInfo_emp_pan_no">PAN</string>
    <string name="EmployeeInfo_emp_passport_no">Passport</string>
    <string name="EmployeeInfo_emp_email">Email</string>
    <string name="EmployeeInfo_emp_addr">Address</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: specify your Q more please ? :\

Comment: post the code u have tried

Comment: Did you design the layout file multi-screen support or not.

Comment: provide screen-shoot please?

Comment: Please put your code in scrollview. for small size device you ui would be not in the screen.Use scrollview as parent. and put all rest code in the scrollview.

Comment: Putting the code inside a scroll view is a very good solution. But, I don't need a scroll view. I want everything to fit inside the screen. Isn't there any other solution?

Comment: @An.R. can u provide a screenshot what u got ?

Comment: @kaushik I am afraid, I don't have enough reputation to upload a screenshot.

Comment: @An.R. use a free image uploading site and post that link here

Answer (score 0):

While launching your device, check the "Scale display to real size" option and provide a higher value for "Screen Size (in)".

Comment: The AVD cuts the screen so he needs to select a smaller value for the AVD Size.

Comment: Regardless of the AVD size, the screen gets cut at Email EditText.

Comment: @An.R. : Can you post your Strings.xml ?
I need it to do a mock-up of your problem at my end.